# Installing Angular/Fire into Angular 17

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have an Angular 17 app and need to add Angular/Fire, the Angular Firebase version to it.

When i try to install it with `npm install @angular/fire` I am faced with a dependency error `npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^16.0.0" from @angular/fire@16.0.0` as the new version of Angular Fire hasn't been released yet.

I stumbled across this thread - https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3459.

I am wondering how to install Angular Fire into 17? Should i use the next version or use `---force`. And where is it initialised now that we no longer have app.module.ts? I used to in app.module.ts but I assume it would be done in app.config.ts or in main?

Comment: By default angular 17 is standalone, so is not using the module structure. (main.ts contains the standalone bootstrapApplication)

Comment: you can try to install it using `--force` and then in app.config.ts's providers array to add `importProvidersFrom(<insert module name here>)`

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work with standalone in Angular 17.

**app.config.ts**

```
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { provideFirebaseApp, getApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment.prod';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideAnimations(), importProvidersFrom([
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
  ])]
};
```

**bookings.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Firestore, collectionData, collection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bookings',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './bookings.component.html',
  styleUrl: './bookings.component.scss'
})
export class BookingsComponent {
  item$: Observable<any[]>;
  firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);

  constructor() {
    const itemCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'guests');
    this.item$ = collectionData(itemCollection);
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "back",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "firebase": "^10.7.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is becasue angular fire was not released for Angular 17.

Try: npm i @angular/fire@17.0.0-next.0

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a day or so looking for a work around and haven't found anything. For future travellers over the next week or two - if you're looking for a way to deploy an Angular 17 app to Firebase Hosting while working with the current version of Angular/Fire (16) or the pre-release version then it will not work together.

I tried -

1. Getting Angular Fire 16 to work with Angular 17 - didn't work
2. Tried using the pre-release version of Angular Fire 17 to work with Angular 17 for deployment to hosting and it didn't work. I tried `ng add @angular/fire@next`
3. I then tried changing the package.json file and adding `"overrides": {  "@angular/fire": {  "@angular/common": "16.0.1",  "@angular/core": "16.0.1",  "@angular/platform-browser": "16.0.1",  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "16.0.1"  } }` and risked running into runtime errors and conflicts and used `npm install --force` and I still can't deploy to hosting.

The next stable version of Angular/Fire should be released in the next couple of weeks but the Thanksgiving period may slow this down.

Also when installing and initialising Angular/Fire everything was set up in my app.config.ts file, which I used to have to do myself in NgModule. You'll still need to set up a separate set of env. folders.

Comment: For what it is worth I'm still using `@angular/fire@^7.6.1` successfully.  I need to use `--legacy-peer-deps` when running npm install, but everything still seems to be working.  rxfire/firebase library conflicts prevent me from using v16 or v17.pre.  Make sure you stay with rxfire 6.0.3 (don't go 6.0.4 or 6.0.5).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't like to use `--fore` or anything else to force the application to work!
Instead I've found a solution that might be useful!
You can use `ng add @angular/fire` ,then this is Angular that decide which version of Angular Firebase will be installed in your project. I think it's gonna be a very good solution for maintainability!