# Angular, Firebase - Can not initialize app with standalone components (nor with standard modules..)

Tags: angular, firebase, debugging, angularfire2

I've been struggling to get my angular project working with firebase today. I have an error:

> main.ts:5 ERROR Error: Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using
> provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported).

Here are my deps:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^17.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.1.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^13.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  }
```

I tried to debug things so I put console.log() inside provideFirebaseApp() function, but it was NEVER CALLED - the console was empty (expect the error posted above)!

```
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(provideFirebaseApp(() => {
      console.log('Before initializing Firebase App');
      return initializeApp({
        some options... (copied from firebase- they are correct)
      })
    })), importProvidersFrom(provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()))]
};
```

After couple hours of fighting, I decided to create new test project and setup firebase right away, and that failed too. I created an angular project with ng new... then I installed dependencies npm i firebase-tools, ng add @angular/fire, followed the process of initializing the app and I tried to check if it is working by calling getFirestore() from OnInit() and got an error...
I have even tried to generate new app without using standalone components, but old NgModules and the result is the same. The console.log inside provideFirebaseApp is never called. Maybe @angular/fire is broke?

I am sure that the app is bootstraping correctly but only without the providers coming from "importProvidersFrom([...]). All other providers (BrowserAnimationModule... etc) are working when provided in appConfig.

Comment: Even when using AngularFireModule.initializeApp({...}) from "@angular/fire/compat" the result is the same - the same error in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so finally I have a solution.

For older versions of Angular + @angular/fire I've been using getfirestore() method from "@angular/fire/firestore";

Now we have to use different approach with injecting the firestore to your component/service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeService{
  private _firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore); //first method

  constructor(private _firestore: Firestore) { //.. or second method
  }

  createDoc(docDetails: any) {
  ... some code, and finally: 
    const docRef= collection(this._firestore, path);
    addDoc(docRef, docDetails).then((docRef) => {
      console.log("Document successfully written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
  }
}
```

Huge thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77587847/7322948

Answer (score 0):

The following app config worked for me, but only after explicitly providing `FIREBASE_OPTIONS`

```js
// app.config.ts

export const APP_CONFIG: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [
        provideRouter(APP_ROUTES),
        provideAnimations(),
        importProvidersFrom(
            provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig))
        ),
        importProvidersFrom(provideStorage(() => getStorage())),
        importProvidersFrom(provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())),
        importProvidersFrom(provideAuth(() => getAuth())),
        importProvidersFrom(provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics())),
        { provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebaseConfig },
        ScreenTrackingService,
        UserTrackingService,
    ],
};
```

```json
// package.json

 "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.1",
        "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
        "@angular/fire": "^17.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
        "@angular/material": "^17.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
        "firebase": "^10.7.1"
      }
```

Note that I do not use the return keyword when accessing `provideFirebaseApp()`. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but adding provider FIREBASE_OPTIONS did not work. 
I tried to downgrade angular to 17.0.0 and still nothing...
I tried some more debugging and it looks like that initializeApp() inside provideFirebaseApp() or even the compat AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase) is never called.